# ios notification from 2 BLE devices

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

In iOS, I connect to 1 peripheral from the scan, discover its services etc. When it is done, I receive notifications from characteristics changes.

I then do the same with another peripheral, while the first one is connected : scan, connect to 2nd peripheral etc.

I will get notifications from the second device, but I will stop receiving notifications from the first one, even though I didn't have any disconnect event from the 1st connected device. Is that normal ?

EDIT :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheral *device1_;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheral *device2_;
```

and given the name of the device I connect to I use one reference or the other

Comment: How are you storing the reference to your connected periperhal?  Do you overwrite the same property/variable when you connect to the second one?

Comment: @Paulw11 see edit. On a callback with `peripheral` as an input, should I use the reference (e.g `device1_` or `peripheral` ?

Comment: I find it is normally easier to use the passed `peripheral`, but it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the properties with 2 private variables and it now works

```
@implementation BLEManager {
  CBCentralManager* centralManager_;
  CBPeripheral* device1_;
  CBPeripheral* device2_;
}

...

@end
```